# array with one value converted to string?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get first element of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921421/get-first-element-of-array)
>   [Convert array to string php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262186/convert-array-to-string-php)

I have this array: `$ tab`.

I perform a `print_r()` it has just this:

```
Array ( [0] => integration ).
```

How to get the value integration without doing `$tab[0]`?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use $tab[0]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use:

```
current($tab);
array_shift($tab); // if you don't need to use the array for anything afterwards
```

Id question why it's in an array in the first place if you don't need it to be and what the issue with using `$tab[0]` is

Comment: Found this answer on Google! so the problem with using [0] is that you may have a random key name or number after an operation.

Answer (score 1):

Well... `$tab[0]` would probably do what you want. I don't see why you wouldn't want that.

Anyway, getting the string should also be possible with `current($tab)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list($integration) = $tab;

echo $integration;
//"integration"
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.ideone.com/R6cRG

```
$array = array('this is a test');
echo current($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about shifting it, like `$tab = $tab[0]`, from which point on you can use just $tab;

Comment: hello guys current does the job. Thanks every body.