# Array to String conversion notice when getting $variable value with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, simplexml, php

Im trying to get the name atriburte of the type element in the following feed using xpath.

```
<response request="getHierarchyByMarketType" code="001" 
          message="success" debug="">    
<jonny>    
  <class id="5" name="Formula 1" maxRepDate="2012-12-19" maxRepTime="15:03:34">    
    <type id="4558" name="F1 Championship" lastUpdateDate="2012-11-26"
          lastUpdateTime="16:17:33">
```

to do this I'm using

```
$market_name = $wh_xml->xpath('/response/jonny/class/type/@name');
```

and then using

```
<h2>
  <?= $market_name ?>
</h2>
```

in my view, but instead of it returning my expected *"F1 Championship"* im getting a:

> Array to string conversion

notice, but I'm not sure why, I thought xpath would return the value of `@name` as a string?

Comment: Related: [Convert array to string php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262186/convert-array-to-string-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *simeplexml* the `xpath()` method always returns an `array`. Because of that, it does not return a string and you see the warning because you used the array as if it were a string (outputting it). When you convert an array to a string in PHP, you will get the notice and the string is *"Array"*.

You find that documented as the `xpath()`s method return-type in the PHP manual: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath and also in the [PHP manual about strings (scroll down/search the following)](http://php.net/language.types.string):

> Arrays are always converted to the string "Array"; because of this, `echo` and `print` can not by themselves show the contents of an array. To view a single element, use a construction such as `echo $arr['foo']`. [...]

The only exception to that rule is if your xpath query contains an error, then the return value will the `FALSE`.

So if you're looking for the first element, you can use the [`list` language construct](http://php.net/list) (if your xpath-query does not have any syntax errors and is returning at least one node):

```
list($market_name) = $wh_xml->xpath('/response/jonny/class/type/@name');
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you're using PHP 5.4 you can also directly access the first array value:

```
$market_name = $wh_xml->xpath('/response/jonny/class/type/@name')[0];
                                                                 ^^^
```

Comment: Related: In my answer to [*"PHP script to echo VLC now playing XML attributes"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16498059/367456) I show [how to extend `SimpleXMLElemnt` to output a string from xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16512153/367456).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: use list() to get just one value instead of an array:

```
list($market_name) = $wh_xml->xpath('//type/@name');
echo $market_name;
```

see it working: http://3v4l.org/rNdMo

Comment: thanks, although this returns the word "Array" - i was also playing with using $market_name[0] in the view, any idea why its happen though ? Are all xpath results returned as arrays ?