# Parsing xml file to get a list

Tags: xml, xpath

I am reading an XML to get the list of airport from IATA.

Below is the xml:

```
array ( 0 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( 'airport' => 'Aalborg, Denmark ', 'code' => 'AAL', )), 1 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( 'airport' => 'Aalesund, Norway ', 'code' => 'AES', )), 2 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( 'airport' => 'Aarhus, Denmark - Bus service ', 'code' => 'ZID', )))
```

I have tried:

```
$list = $xml->xpath("//airport");
display_output($list[0]);
```

I am getting:

```
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( ))
```

How can I get?

```
Aalborg, Denmark
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is not the xml. Could you have a look at the xml-file at githubusercontent?

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dodyg/AndroidRivers/master/assets/airports.xml | xmllint --xpath '//iata/iata_airport_codes[code="AAL"]' -
<iata_airport_codes>
        <airport>Aalborg, Denmark</airport>
        <code>AAL</code>
    </iata_airport_codes>
```

Below gives you your example output;

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dodyg/AndroidRivers/master/assets/airports.xml | xmllint --xpath '//iata/iata_airport_codes[code="AAL"]/airport/text()' -
Aalborg, Denmark
```

To get the same result with PHP (get the first item of the array);

```
$airport = $xml->xpath('//iata/iata_airport_codes[code="AAL"]/airport/text()')[0];
echo $airport
```

Comment: That is the same file which I have downloaded from IATA. when I used the xpath you are using 

$list = $xml->xpath('//iata/iata_airport_codes[code="AAL"]/airport/text()');
                display_output($list);

I am getting this:

array ( 0 => SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array( )), )

Comment: That is because it returns an array, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219060/array-to-string-conversion-notice-when-getting-variable-value-with-xpath