# Incorrectly used array_multisort() giving correct result?

Tags: php, array-multisort

I'm currently touching some legacy code in an attempt to clean it and have come across something of a puzzle. **It's not even remotely mission critical that I resolve it,** so consider this a sporting question at most, but it's still perplexing me. Colour me curious.

This code:

```
// dummy data for the sake of testing / abstract visualisation;
// x is thrown in as an experiment:
$workTables = array(
    array('x' => 5, 'Name' => 'foo3', 'Update_time' => '2013-04-04 04:40',),
    array('x' => 4, 'Name' => 'foo4', 'Update_time' => '2013-04-01 04:40',),
    array('x' => 3, 'Name' => 'foo2', 'Update_time' => '2013-04-04 09:40',),
    array('x' => 2, 'Name' => 'foo1', 'Update_time' => '2013-04-12 04:40',),
    array('x' => 1, 'Name' => 'foo5', 'Update_time' => '2012-12-04 04:40',),
);

// original legacy code:
if (!empty($workTables)) {
    $sort = array();
    foreach ($workTables as $key => $value) {
        $sort[$key]["Update_time"] = $value["Update_time"];
    }
    array_multisort($workTables, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $sort);
}
```

...while throwing twelve notices ("`Notice: Array to string conversion ...`"), works *as expected*, by ordering all elements in `$workTables` according to `Update_time`.

(The 'x' column is part of my attempt to rule out that it has anything to do with `Name`, which in the original code is a fixed prefix followed by a timestamp (e.g. `work_table_1367940392`, `work_table_1367940395`, ...), making sorting by `Name` equivalent to sorting by `Update_time`.)

Obviously, since [I don't want to program by coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence), at the very least this is going to be replaced with:

```
// new code:
if (!empty($workTables)) {
    $sort = array();
    foreach ($workTables as $key => $value) {
        $sort[$key] = $value["Update_time"];
    }
    array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $workTables);
}
```

...which conforms to the description of **[`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array_multisort)**, *also* does what we want, and doesn't throw Notices in our face.

**But what I'm really interested in is *why* the old code works (notices notwithstanding).**

A partial reason seems to be the behaviour of **[`asort()`](http://php.net/asort)** and co., which have the (partly) undocumented feature that they can work with multi-dimensional arrays by acting according to the contents of the array, working through the structure from "left to right" (at least in `PHP 5.4.7 (cli)`)... but... I'm stuck trying to comprehend what's making `$workTables` and `$sort` '*interchangable*'.

I've tried to look at PHP's C source code to figure it out, but I'm stuck at trying to understand what happens here:

```
/* Do the actual sort magic - bada-bim, bada-boom. */
zend_qsort(indirect, array_size, sizeof(Bucket **), php_multisort_compare TSRMLS_CC);
```

...since my knowledge of C has rusted terribly and `zend_qsort()` itself is just flatly out of my league.

Any takers?

Keep in mind I'm not desperate for an answer, so don't sink too much time into this, but maybe someone else likes a puzzle, too? :)

Personally, I've invested some time into this purely because I prefer understanding code thoroughly, especially when I'm trying to clean it up - even if it's code that works only by coincidence. I've just reached a dead-end when it comes to further comprehension, so stackoverflow seemed like the best chance for further enlightenment.

So, if you have an idea about what's going on behind the scenes (I suspect it's something trivial I've overlooked; that tends to be my problem after going around in circles for a while), I'd love to hear it! :)

Comment: the bada-bim, bada-boom comment really gives it away..

Comment: @Raidenace: Haha, I know, right? It explains *everything*. :) (To be fair, I thought it was great - humourous comments are a rare (if ambiguous) pleasure to behold.)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, an array is being created and stored in `$sort[$key]`. Then, once you call `array_multisort()`, it happens to convert the array back into a string and sort using that string as the value that defines the order -- just as the warning says. Then, this string is used as the order-defining value.

How is this conversion array->string performed? Just doing `echo $anArrayValueHere;` is not helpful; it prints out `Array`. Similar trick, `echo "" . $anArrayValueHere . "";` also doesn't yield anything useful. (But neither does it yield a notice!)

It's quite possible that [`serialize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6262396/39974) is used. Presuming that, let's see what would get used as a order-defining value:

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
<?php
$sort[0]["Update_time"] = '2012-12-04 04:40';
echo serialize($sort[0]);
```

then

```
$ ./php tmp.php
a:1:{s:11:"Update_time";s:16:"2012-12-04 04:40";}
```

It looks like the key would be sufficiently definitive to yield something usable to define sort order just as well as just the `Update_time` value would.

I'm not sure that `serialize()` is used, but if it is, I think this is the explanation.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see any evidence of `serialize()` (and it would be strange for `serialize()` to throw the conversion warning), but... that could also just be due to my complete disorientation in the C code. :) I'm fairly sure the ordering itself is due to `sort()` and co's multidimensional-array handling (`sort()` also uses `zend_qsort()`), the odder question to me is still the interchangability of the arrays.

Comment: "(But neither does it yield a notice!)" doesn't hold true on my machine, by the way, but that just as a sidenote for completion's sake. I gotta say, though, thank you so much for your stab at this! :) I wish I had more than one upvote to give you.